# How to handle imaginary numbers with total square error questions

Tags: math, linear-algebra

I am pretty new to algrebra so if u can use simple terms and explain a bit more it would be helpfull. Ive been trying to use imaginary numbers to get the total square error of a graph of a non linear equation. i figure theres a way to calculate a near perfect equation just using x and i without squareing x or anything to get a 0 or closer square error. And it would help if i cancled out some how so im left with a normal number or something.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.